# Get customProperies from Outlook events added by web add-in

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I've created an Outlook add-in that saves some custom properties to an event.
Below is a code snippet showing how these properties are added.

```js
async saveToCustomProperties(selectedTask, taskId, selectedScope, ordererId, selectedWorkplace, workplaceId) {
        try {
            const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(result => {
                    resolve(result)
                })
            })

            if (result.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.log(`Action failed with message ${result.error.message}`)
                return
            }

            const customProperties = result.value
            customProperties.set('task', selectedTask.textContent)
            customProperties.set('taskId', taskId)
            customProperties.set('orderer', selectedScope.textContent)
            customProperties.set('ordererId', ordererId)
            customProperties.set('workplace', selectedWorkplace.textContent)
            customProperties.set('workplaceId', workplaceId)

            const saveResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                customProperties.saveAsync(result => {
                    resolve(result)
                })
            })

            if (saveResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                console.log(`Action failed with message ${saveResult.error.message}`)
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`An error occurred: ${error}`)
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to download them now using Graph Explorer but I'm failing. I don't know if I'm constructing the GET query correctly.

I tried this but got an error.
{WebAddinID} - id of the add-on from the manifest placed in the  tags

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/{calendarID}/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-08-07T19:00:00Z&endDateTime=2023-08-10T19:00:00Z&$select=Subject,Start,End,singleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} cecp-{WebAddinID}')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} cecp-{WebAddinID}' and ep/value ne null)
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
        "message": "PropertyId values may only be in one of the following formats: 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Name propertyName', 'MapiPropertyType namespaceGuid Id propertyId' or 'MapiPropertyType propertyTag'."
    }
}
```

I found such a solution, but it returns the Subject of this event. I know it's because of the "String 0x0037" property, but I don't know where it comes from.

```http
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendars/AAMkADgyNDMwM2ZjLTExYWUtNGQ5OS05NTgwLWFiZjlmZDg4NWI1OQBGAAAAAABMPKKLL5lWRLP95mo_mxaPBwDmaU3JUTI2TLstD4TeI_4TAAAAAAEGAADmaU3JUTI2TLstD4TeI_4TAAAMfksaAAA=/calendarView?startDateTime=2023-08-07T19:00:00Z&endDateTime=2023-08-10T19:00:00Z&$select=Subject,Start,End,singleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0037')&$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep: ep/id eq 'String 0x0037' and ep/value ne null)
```

From what I understand, it's constructing the propertyId wrong. Could someone help me?

Comment: It should be: ($filter=id eq 'String {00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} Name cecp-{WebAddinID}') Please note Name keyword before name of your property.